# setting up anacron for version control update

Tags: 12.04, cron, anacron

I store some of my configuration files in version control. Recently I tried to setup a daily anacron job so that I won't have to manually update the files. I have never used cron or anacron before but reading through [cron documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) I decided to put my script in `/etc/cron.daily`. Below is my script named `dot-files` (changed to executable with `chmod +x`):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/dell/dot-files && /usr/bin/git add . && /usr/bin/git commit -a -m 'daily update' && /usr/bin/git push -u origin master
```

However it doesn't seem to be running for the last two days. Here are the lines from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug 21 10:42:02 dell-Studio-1535 anacron[1023]: Job `cron.daily' terminated (exit status: 1) (mailing output)
Aug 21 10:42:02 dell-Studio-1535 anacron[1023]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with that? Also am I using a wrong setup for the purpose?

**p.s.** I'm using an ubuntu 12.04 system and it's not always running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first things first. You don't see what went wrong because cron could not mail you the output. Instead, however, of configuring your sendmail, modify your script such that it stores the output of your commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

export workdir=/home/dell
export logfile=$workdir/dot-files.log
export errfile=$workdir/dot-files.err
date >> $logfile
date >> $errfile

{ cd $workdir/dot-files && /usr/bin/git add . && /usr/bin/git commit -a -m 'daily update' && /usr/bin/git push -u origin master ; } >> $logfile 2>> $errfile
```

Furthermore, you do not need to put it into the cron directly as root, you can run crontab as user.

```
man crontab
```

P.S. What happens when you run that script manually?

Comment: turned out my scripts were not running manually either. thank you for the suggestion. I have tried to setup an ssh connection for git so that I won't have to deal with username and password in the script, I guess something went wrong. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: script is fixed now. so about that `crontab`, I was trying to use `anacron` in the first place because my computer is not always on. is it possible to set `crontab` to work once a day independent of the hours it is on/off?